# How concatenate a TCHAR array to left side?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, concatenation, tchar

I want concat the string **-jar** to left side of a path the is **C:\Users\NZT48\AppData\Roaming** where final result must be like:

*-jar C:\Users\NZT48\AppData\Roaming*

Have tried with code below, but when concatenates the path with the string **-jar** is overwritting and stays only the string of path.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    TCHAR argjar[MAX_PATH];

    TCHAR szRoaming[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hRoaming = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szRoaming);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hRoaming))
    {
        printf("SHGetFolderPath function failed.\n");
    }

    wsprintf(argjar, TEXT("%S -jar "), argjar);
    wsprintf(argjar, szRoaming , argjar);  // My problem is here

    printf("%S\n", argjar);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `wsprintf(argjar, L"-jar %s", szRoaming);`

Comment: Why can't you just construct the string once with `wsprintf`? If you're using `wsprintf` why are you also using `TCHAR`? Why are you mixing that with `printf`? You really should pick one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank very much, worked fine.

Comment: Unless you're still trying to support Windows versions prior to XP, there's no reason to still be using TCHAR.